# Powershellでtry-catchのcatch内でエラーが起きるとcatch外が実行されてしまう

Tags: powershell

初めての質問で慣れておらず、失礼がありましたら、お許しください。
タイトルに書いたような事象がおきております。
下記のようなプログラムを作成し実行すると1回目は正常終了します。
その後、C:\hoge1\hogeを読取専用(またはプログラムを別ユーザで実行)すると、Stop-TranScriptでエラーが起きた後、catch以降の文が実行されてしまいます。
どうもcatch内でエラーが起こると、後続の文を中断して、catch外の文が実行されてしまうように見えます。
回避する方法があれば、アドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。(Win10_20H2で確認)

```
Start-TranScript -Path C:\hoge1\hoge
try {
    echo hoge > C:\hoge2\hogehoge   #存在しないフォルダ
}
catch {
    echo $_.Exception.Message
    Stop-TranScript
    exit 5
}
echo "なぜかここが実行される"
```

Comment: この記事 [PowerShell - Nesting Try/Catch/Finally Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32522983/9014308) のように元の`catch`の中に更に`try/catch`を入れて、その`finally`に`exit 5`を入れてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 2):

PowerShellは他のシェルスクリプトと同様に、エラーが発生しても処理を継続します。この動作は [Common Parameter の `-ErrorAction`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1#-erroraction) で制御できます。
デフォルトは `-ErrorAction Continue` ですが、`-ErrorAction Stop` を指定すれば停止します。

しかし、質問は `>` によるリダイレクトであり、

```
echo hoge > C:\hoge2\hogehoge
```

は内部的には

```
Write-Output hoge | Out-File C:\hoge2\hogehoge
```

となっています。

```
Write-Output hoge | Out-File -ErrorAction Stop C:\hoge2\hogehoge
```

とすれば止まりますが、元のリダイレクト記法ではパラメーターを指定することができません。この場合でも、[Preference Variable の `$ErrorActionPreference`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-5.1#erroractionpreference) で制御できます。実行前に

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
echo hoge > C:\hoge2\hogehoge
```

で処理を止めることができます。

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。
ただ、実際に実行してみてもらえましたでしょうか？
try-catchは、問題なくできております。
再度読んでいただければ思いますが、catch内でエラーが起きた場合に次のexit 5がスキップされてしまうという不具合になります。